# Sending variables with php works with chrome but not in any other browser

Tags: php, variables, session

I understand that php is server side, so the browser shouldn't matter.

However, if I use this code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['varName'] = $myusername;
header("location:login_success.php");
```

Then, in chrome, the variable is tranferred over to "login_success.php"

But in Firefox and Safari, this does not work.

I do not understand why this is because the client should not matter.

Comment: What doesn't work, the redirect or just the variable is not available on the next page?

Comment: The redirect works but the variable is not available on the next page

Comment: Cookies are enabled in all browsers?  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: You should check the return values of `session_start()` in both files. Also, are you doing anything after the redirect? You should `exit;` there to make sure no further code is executed.

Comment: Have you used any session based condition on login_success.php? add session_start(); on login_success.php too. May be this will solve your issue.

Comment: Cookies are enabled and after putting in some exit commands, the variable still only transfers in Chrome